Iterate over folder name list to copy folder if existing
This is how I copy the folder src from source to workspace destination - replacing the content if already existing:
def copy_and_replace(directory):
    target = os.path.join('workspace', directory, 'src')
    source = os.path.join('..', 'source', directory, 'src')
    try:
        if os.path.isdir(target):
            shutil.rmtree(target)
            print(f"Directory removed successfully: {target}")
        shutil.copytree(source, target)
        print(f"Directory copied successfully: {target}")

    except OSError as o:
        print(f"Error, {o.strerror}: {directory}")

Now I would like to define two more folders, which should also be copied if existing. Of course I could do this like this:
def copy_and_replace(directory):
    targetSrc = os.path.join('workspace', directory, 'src')
    sourceSrc = os.path.join('..', 'source', directory, 'src')
    targetPbl = os.path.join('workspace', directory, 'public')
    sourcePbl = os.path.join('..', 'source', directory, 'public')
    try:
        if os.path.isdir(targetSrc): # src folder is always existing
            shutil.rmtree(targetSrc)
            print(f"Directory removed successfully: {targetSrc}")
        shutil.copytree(sourceSrc, targetSrc)
        print(f"Directory copied successfully: {targetSrc}")

        if os.path.isdir(sourcePbl): # Check if public folder is existing in source
            if os.path.isdir(targetPbl):
                shutil.rmtree(targetPbl)
                print(f"Directory removed successfully: {targetPbl}")
            shutil.copytree(sourcePbl, targetPbl)
            print(f"Directory copied successfully: {targetPbl}")

        # do this last part for multiple folder like `specs`, `assets` and so on

    except OSError as o:
        print(f"Error, {o.strerror}: {directory}")

Is it possible to use a list of folder names and iterate over those items to check of folder is existing in source, and if it is exsting to copy it to target workspace?

Yes it's possible

Of course it is possible
from os.path import join
def copy_and_replace(directory):
    paths = [
        [join('..', 'source', directory, 'src'), join('workspace', directory, 'src')],
        [join('..', 'source', directory, 'public'), join('workspace', directory, 'public')]
    ]

    for src, target in paths:

        try:
            if os.path.isdir(target): # src folder is always existing
                shutil.rmtree(target)
                print(f"Directory removed successfully: {target}")
            shutil.copytree(src, target)
            print(f"Directory copied successfully: {target}")

        except OSError as o:
            print(f"Error, {o.strerror}: {directory}")

If you want to be less specific, and you know that the directories source and target are at the same place you can do
def copy_and_replace(directory):
    paths = ["src", "public"]

    for path in paths:
        src = os.path.join('..', 'source', directory, path)
        target = os.path.join('workspace', directory, path)
        ...


Yes it's possible.
import os
import shutil

def copy_and_replace(directory, folders_to_copy):
    target_src = os.path.join('workspace', directory, 'src')
    source_src = os.path.join('..', 'source', directory, 'src')
    
    try:
        # Remove and copy the 'src' folder
        if os.path.isdir(target_src):
            shutil.rmtree(target_src)
            print(f"Directory removed successfully: {target_src}")
        shutil.copytree(source_src, target_src)
        print(f"Directory copied successfully: {target_src}")

        # Iterate over additional folders to copy
        for folder_name in folders_to_copy:
            source_folder = os.path.join('..', 'source', directory, folder_name)
            target_folder = os.path.join('workspace', directory, folder_name)

            if os.path.isdir(source_folder):
                if os.path.isdir(target_folder):
                    shutil.rmtree(target_folder)
                    print(f"Directory removed successfully: {target_folder}")
                shutil.copytree(source_folder, target_folder)
                print(f"Directory copied successfully: {target_folder}")

    except OSError as o:
        print(f"Error, {o.strerror}: {directory}")

# Example usage
folders_to_copy = ['public', 'specs', 'assets']  # List of additional folders to copy
copy_and_replace('example_directory', folders_to_copy)

